# How to count matching values from both columns in R?

Tags: r, matching

I'm having trouble figuring how to do this and I can't seem to find an answer so help would be greatly appreciated. What I'm trying to do is to count certain matching values for example if column x has a b and column y has an a it is counted as one/matches and its done until the last row.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("b","c","a","d","f","b","c","b"), y = c("a","b","c","a","d","a","f","a"))
```

```
> df
  x y
1 b a
2 c b
3 a c
4 d a
5 f d
6 b a
7 c f
8 b a
```

What I've tried is something like this:

```
b <- x == "b"
a <- y == "a"
b[a]
```

What I've assumed is that b finds any rows that has a, if that makes sense.

Comment: `table(df)["b","a"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "and" operator `&` to combine logical conditions indicating when they are both true, and `sum()` to count the number of times a logical condition is true. I think you want

```
sum(df$x == "b" & df$y == "a")
# [1] 3
```

Notice how nicely this mirrors your language. You said "*x has a "b" and column y has an "a"*".

```
# x has a "b"  and  y has an "a"
  x == "b"      &    y == "a"
```

You would use the "or" operator `|` if you wanted to see how many times x had a "b" *or* y had an "a".

Answer (score 1):

if the data is not extremely huge, you could compute everything at once then just use subscript:

```
df1 <- table(df)


df1["b", "a"]#for x=="b"  and  y=="a"
[1] 3
df1["a", "b"]#for x=="a"  and  y=="b"
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   summarise(new = sum(x == 'b'  & y == 'a'))
```